# Founder badge description missed "definition" update

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, area-51, badge-description

> ● Founder — **Dicussed**, committed, and participated in the Beta of a successful site

Comment: There's a typo there, but the larger issue is "discussion" was renamed to "definition".  Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks!  This has been fixed.